# Elgg entity listing not working

Tags: php, elgg

**Elgg 2.1.1**

I'm trying to create a custom elgg listing page that should list `objects` of subtype `bread`, but the page in `/views/default/object/bread.php` doesn't get picked up. What could I be doing wrong?

**/views/default/object/bread.php**

```
echo elgg_view_title($vars['entity']->title);
echo elgg_view('output/longtext', array('value' => $vars['entity']->description));
echo elgg_view('output/tags', array('tags' => $vars['entity']->tags));
```

**/views/default/resources/bread/bread.php**

```
<?php

echo elgg_view_title($vars['entity']->title);
echo elgg_view('output/longtext', array('value' => $vars['entity']->description));
echo elgg_view('output/tags', array('tags' => $vars['entity']->tags));

$body = elgg_list_entities(array(
    'type' => 'object',
    'subtype' => 'bread',
));

$body = elgg_view_layout('one_column', array('content' => $body));

echo elgg_view_page("All Loaves of Bread", $body);
```

Comment: Is your list empty, or you get listings with default view?

Comment: Just figured it. I didn't know that I had to name the `/views/default/object/bread.php` file same as the object name. Sorry about that. Thank you for the help though @hypeJunction. In my project I had named them differently, not like I show in the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should answer your own question and give a proper answer in case someone else is running into this problem.

Comment: Will certainly do.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have added the view while System Cache is enabled. Flush the caches, or disable the cache during development (Admin > Settings > Advanced settings).

Comment: Thank you for the response @hypeJunction. I have all caches disabled. Both simple cache and system cache are off.